# Change text item choice

Tags: jquery

hello I have many elements so if I click on any one of them I can modify the text but 
in my code
-if I click on any element it go always to change the last one only not element selected 
-another Question how can I make a copy of each element if I click in icon edit

```js
$(".edit").click(function() {
  $('.edit').each(function(index) {
    $(".item").get(index).contentEditable = "true";
    $(".item").focus();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocgloab">
  <div class="blocimage">
    <button class="nobutton edit"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/badge_edit-128.png"></button>
    <button class="nobutton cloner"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/130/130992.png"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="hovermodule1" data-id="itemdat-1" class="item disable " draggable="true">
    Lorum1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blocgloab">
  <div class="blocimage">
    <button class="nobutton edit"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/badge_edit-128.png"></button>
    <button class="nobutton cloner"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/130/130992.png"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="hovermodule2" data-id="itemdat-2" class="item disable " draggable="true">
    Lorum2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blocgloab">
  <div class="blocimage">
    <button class="nobutton edit"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/badge_edit-128.png"></button>
    <button class="nobutton cloner"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/130/130992.png"></button>
  </div>
  <div id="hovermodule3" data-id="itemdat-3" class="item " draggable="true">
    Lorum3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: If you clone a block you will have to manually adjust the `id="hovermoduleN"` and `data-id="itemdat-3"` and text since an id MUST be unique and you seem to want the data-id and text to sync with the positional of the block

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is because you're looping through *all* `.item` elements and calling `focus()` on them. Only one element at a time can receive focus, so it will the last one you called it on in the loop.

I assume instead that you want to set `contenteditable` and `focus()` on the `.item` related to the `.edit` element which was clicked. In order to use that you can use jQuery's DOM traversal methods; `closest()` and `next()` in this case.

To clone an element you can call `clone()` on it. I presume you mean to do this on the `.cloner` element given its context in the UI. Then you can add the clone back in to the DOM where necessary.

Also note that for the `.edit` and `.cloner` links to work in the clone itself you need to use delegated event handlers, and you will need to remove the `id` attributes from the elements you clone, otherwise you will have duplicates which is invalid.

With all that said, try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '.edit', function() {
  $(this).closest('.blocimage').next('.item').prop('contenteditable', true).focus();
});

$(document).on('click', '.cloner', function() {
  var $clone = $(this).closest('.blocgloab').clone();
  $clone.insertAfter('.blocgloab:last');
});
```

```css
.item {
  outline: 0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="blocgloab">
  <div class="blocimage">
    <button class="nobutton edit"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/badge_edit-128.png"></button>
    <button class="nobutton cloner"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/130/130992.png"></button>
  </div>
  <div data-id="itemdat-1" class="item disable " draggable="true">
    Lorum1
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blocgloab">
  <div class="blocimage">
    <button class="nobutton edit"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/badge_edit-128.png"></button>
    <button class="nobutton cloner"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/130/130992.png"></button>
  </div>
  <div data-id="itemdat-2" class="item disable " draggable="true">
    Lorum2
  </div>
</div>
<div class="blocgloab">
  <div class="blocimage">
    <button class="nobutton edit"><img src="https://cdn2.iconfinder.com/data/icons/picol-vector/32/badge_edit-128.png"></button>
    <button class="nobutton cloner"><img src="https://image.flaticon.com/icons/png/128/130/130992.png"></button>
  </div>
  <div data-id="itemdat-3" class="item " draggable="true">
    Lorum3
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thank you very much but it's possible if i cloned the id it changes and text forem lorum1copy

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean.

Comment: sorry if I clic on clone it add new element but it change the id and the text

Comment: Could also use a deep copy with `.clone(true);` to retain any events not directly associated with the ones in the code.   Those in your example are hooked to the document so that also works as a solution.

Comment: @Thomas-anderson002anderson002 do you mean that you want to change the text of the div when cloning? If so use `text()`: https://api.jquery.com/text

Comment: @Thomas-anderson002anderson002 that seems like a new/different question to me

Comment: I have a little problem,when I click on the text, there is a focus how to disable I want  only edits going by click in icone edit